# Where does openssh decrypt and react to received packets?

Tags: cryptography, encryption, openssh, encryption-symmetric

I am trying to add a second layer of encryption (encrypted on the client side, and decrypted on the server side).

EDIT: I apologize if I wasn't clear. I was looking for the function in the OpenSSH source in C where the ssh connection on the server side responds to activity from the client side. I did end up finding what I was looking for...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! It is in the file **channels.c** and in the function **void channel_input_data(int type, u_int32_t seq, void *ctxt)**.

Comment: At this point you can accept your own answer so it will show up as answered for others who perform a search.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson Thanks for the heads up! Unfortunately I can't accept it for another 20 hours, perhaps because my rating is too low or because I've posted it so recently.